# PDF Attachments in Azure, use memory or temporary directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, pdf-generation

I'm planning on writing an application that sends multiple PDFs to the users' emails as attachments.

Should I use memory (MemoryStream) or is there a temporary directory that I can use? Which is more advisable? Thanks!

BTW I'm using C# ASP.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with file-system storage, since memory is a more scarce resource. Windows Azure provides Local Storage Resources for this purpose, which are areas of disk that you configure in Service Definition and then access through the Azure SDK at runtime. They are not permanent storage, and will get cleaned up when a role recycles, thus they are ideal for temporary operations such as the one you describe. Although you should still try to clean up the files after each operation to make sure you don't fill up the space.

Full information on Local Storage Resources is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx

A table detailing the amount of disk space available for Local Storage Resources on each instance size is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee814754.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this mark! I was wondering though, what if I have multiple instances, do they share the same local storage resource?

Comment: No, they don't, it's a separate resource for each instance. If you want to share, you should use blob storage.

Comment: I see.. Wouldn't I run the risk of storing it in one instance and then when I'm going to attach it, the file wouldn't be found?

Comment: Only if you spread the process over multiple instances. If you're running these as batch processes within a worker role, then you would generate all the PDFs and the email in a single process on a single instance. Processes don't skip about over instances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different pattern.  Put the PDFs in blob storage and place a queue message with the e-mail address & list of PDFs to send.  Have a separate worker role build & send the e-mail.  You could use X-Small or Small.  Since this would also allow for asynch communication, you could just use 1 instance.  If it can't keep up, spin up a second one via the config file (i.e. no re-deployment).  This also has the added benefit of giving your solution more aggregate bandwidth.

If the traffic isn't very heavy, you could just spin up a separate thread (or process) that does the same thing.

Pat